# how to save file path after move it from a directory to another in java

Tags: java

I copy a file from a directory for another but I have a difficulty to find the new file path !
I used FileUtils class from apache commons-io library to do that..... please is that there a function can  save the last file path ?

Answer (score 1):

Since FileUtils.moveFile accepts two arguments -- source file and destination file, all you need to do is to use second arg:

```
File myFile = new File("file");
File newLocation = new File("funky_file");
FileUtils.copyFile(myFile, newLocation);
myFile = newLocation;
```

You cannot retrive new location basing only on myFile without reassigning: File class is designed to be a immutable path rather that hard link to the file.

Comment: SO how we can retrive new location without file class ? I need a hard link to the file